# Best solution to add search feature to my app

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, searchview, android-search

I want to add search feature via `ActionBar` `SearchView` to my app. I've succesfully added the `SearchView` and searchable config there and it works well. I have a custom `ListView` and the objects are stored at [Parse.com](http://parse.com/).  Right now am I facing a question, what is the best way to do it an my case. I want the search to do:

- When the user is typing, show suggestions
- When the user submits the query, show new `Activity` with search results

What would you recommend me to do? 
*(For better imagination how does it look like now see the picture.)*

Thank you very much

I want to search by the name of the animal. (`.getAnimal()` in my code)
[image: It looks like this now]

Comment: Just a tip : under the DDMS tools, you should have a button to take a screenshot of your device. Better than taking a picture of your phone's screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt know this. I had to do it like this, because i didnt find solution how to take screenshot on htc desire.

Comment: Glad I could help ! In Android Studio (don't remember if also in Eclipse), there's even an option to stick the screen shot in a device ("frame screenshot" option), add a drop shadow to the device mockup and even screen glare. Very useful for the Play Store screen caps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: It provides the suggestions while typing, am I right?

Comment: Yes:-), you just need to provide the data to it.